# upload image - 404 not found eror - with ant design Form and Upload components

Tags: image, upload, antd

i am using ant-d components in my react app.

this is the part of the Form i having problem with:

```
<Form.Item
    name={["product", "image"]}
    rules={[
        {
            required: false,
        },
    ]}
    getValueFromEvent={normFile}
>
    <Upload.Dragger
        name="files"
        // action="/upload.do"
        >
        <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
            <UploadOutlined />
        </p>
        <p className="ant-upload-text">
            לחץ והוסף קובץ תמונה או גרור את הקובץ ישירות לתיבה זו
        </p>
    </Upload.Dragger>
</Form.Item>
```

when i am choosing a file i getting directly this 404 eror:

request.js:109 POST http://localhost:3000/adminLogIn 404 (Not Found)

what am i missing?